# Ubuntu won't boot to desktop after disconnecting and then re-connecting SSD

Tags: boot, ssd, bootloader

I think it can still read the disk as the splash screen is there.
This is the output I get:

[image]

I looked at `journalctl -xb`, but didn't know how to interpret that.
Basically default mode isn't working. Tried `systemctl reboot`, which I guess default settings with extra step, also didn't work.

Comment: Press Enter, try `fsck -a`, or boot from your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode, and `fsck` your disk's partitions.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried `fsck` with a new live usb. it has worked so far.